# Why do we need bulky filters at the input stage of SMPS designs?

Tags: filter, switch-mode-power-supply, input, common-mode

I usually see costly and large filters at the input stage of switch mode power supplies. Isn't the AC signal already filtered by the large capacitor (the 100\$\mu\$F one in this example) after the bridge rectifier? What is the necessity of such an elaborated filter network encircled in red?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe to prevent noise leaking out of the power supply back onto the mains, i.e. compliance with regulations.

Comment: Why do you call the above a SMPS?  It looks to be rectifying the AC mains.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I didn't post the entire circuit. I only posted the input section. The whole circuit is an SMPS structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular instance, the circuit is not using active PFC (power factor control), so I think that the extreme amount of filtering is an attempt to meet regulatory requirements by using "passive" PFC (harmonic filtering) to correct the harmonic distortion created by the rectifier/DC filter combination. Note that the cutoff frequency of the filter is only about 3 kHz, which is much lower than it would need to be if it were just dealing with switching noise from the regulator.

Answer (score 6):

It's to stop high-frequency noise (100kHz or higher) from getting out of the SMPS and onto the mains. If the noise got out that way, it would radiate via the mains wiring and that's an EMC problem. The big capacitor (100uF, 160V) will not be effective for this, due to its ESR and other factors. The filter components specifically filter out the high fequency noise.

Answer (score 0):

It is for removing switching ripple from entering into mains.

Because when switching occurs in converter ( SMPS ) ckt at high frequncy ( 50 or 100 k or so ), ripple gets induced in SMPS ckt.

By introducing capacitor we try to regulate SMPS output to optimum required value.